# Package installer has stopped when manually installing app through signed APK

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in Android programming and I need some help. I generated signed APK of my app and manually installed in other phones. I got error "Unfortunately, package installer has stopped". I got the same message even if I install debug APK. Please help.

Comment: While making the apk, did you select both V1 and V2 jars?

Comment: yes, i selected both v1 and v2..plz help

Comment: While running directly from computer, did you get such error?

Comment: No, it works fine while running directly from computer but not working from signed and debug apk

Comment: How many things you have installed in your `SDK Manager` -> `SDK Tools` section?

Comment: check https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145169/cant-install-apk-from-package-installer

Comment: also check https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-applications-without-the-market/

Comment: Yes, I have installed all the tools in SDK -> tools except intel HAXM